# How to prove that all Ternary representations (using $0$ and $2$ only) of the elements of the cantor set are distinct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

There is a bijection between elements of $C$ and infinite sequences of $0$’s and $2$’s: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n3^{-n}\mapsto\langle a_1,a_2,\dots\rangle\;.$$

I know we will have uncountable such sequences.

That is why we will have uncountable such series. So the cantor set is uncountable.

But how we are knowing that each of the series is distinct ?

Can anyone please help me to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n3^{-n}=\sum_{n\ge 1}b_n3^{-n}\,.$$

If the sequences $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ and $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ are different, let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $a_m\ne b_m$; without loss of generality we may assume that $a_m=0$ and $b_m=2$. Then

$$\sum_{n>m}a_n3^{-n}=2\cdot3^{-m}+\sum_{n>m}b_n3^{-n}\,.\tag{1}$$

But

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n>m}a_n3^{-n}&\le\sum_{n>m}2\cdot3^{-n}\\
&=\frac{2\cdot3^{-(m+1)}}{1-\frac13}\\
&=3^{-m}\\
&<2\cdot3^{-m}+\sum_{n>m}b_n3^{-n}\,,
\end{align*}$$

so $(1)$ is impossible, and $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ and $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ must be the same sequence.